# How do I cron an ipython jupyter notebook's cells?

Tags: python, cron, ipython, jupyter

I have an ipython jupyter notebook that I've developed and run from Django 1.8 with:

```
manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Within the notebook I have written some data analytics and reporting modules that produce CSV and HTML output via petl and pandas.

I'd like to automate the notebook in such a way that I can simply cron the notebook cells to execute and then serve the static HTML output, but I don't see a way to run the cells within the notebook without a human driving the process, i.e. from cron.

Comment: `ipython nbconvert` has a `--execute` flag to run a notebook before converting it to e.g. HTML.

Comment: Could you add that as an answer and I'll mark it answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nbconvert has a `--execute` flag to run a notebook before converting it to another format.

So for instance, to run a notebook and convert to static HTML:

```
ipython nbconvert --execute --to html MyNotebook.ipynb
```

If you want to run it and save the results as an ipynb file, you can use `--to notebook`.